# Marking values beyond limits in line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's assume this dataset,

```
seed(1234)    
serial <- rep(1:50)
change <- rnorm(n=50, m=1, sd=1) 
data <- data.frame(serial, change)
summary(change)
```

Now let's plot a line,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = serial, y = change)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ylab(label="Change") + 
  xlab("Serial")
```

which gives me this output,
[image]

Now, I want to mark (a red circle perhaps, or the serial number) every data points which is above 2.0 and below -0.5.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the dataset in the call to `geom_point`. Then use the new values of `x` and `y` to plot only those points.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = serial, y = change)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = subset(data, change > 2.0 | change < -0.5),
             aes(x = serial, y = change, color = "red")) +
  ylab(label="Change") + 
  xlab("Serial")
```

[image]

To plot the values of `serial`, numbers, the best way is to use `geom_text`, setting appropriate `label` values. First I plot the values greater than `2.0` and then the values less than `-0.5`. This is because the aesthetics `vjust` will have different values depending on placing the labels above or below the points.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = serial, y = change)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(data, change > 2.0),
            aes(x = serial, y = change, 
                color = "red", label = serial, vjust = -0.5),
            show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data = subset(data, change < -0.5),
            aes(x = serial, y = change, 
                color = "red", label = serial, vjust = 1),
            show.legend = FALSE) + 
  ylab(label="Change") + 
  xlab("Serial")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works. Any way to show the serial number on the plot too?

Comment: @hmhsl consider creating a dummy variable as I outline in my answer.

Comment: @EcologyTom Got it. I just need to add `  geom_text(aes(label=serial),hjust=0, vjust=0)`.

Answer (score 1):

@Rui's answer is neat, and probably the option I would go for.

Having said that, you might want to avoid subsetting in ggplot, for readability if nothing else. I would suggest creating a dummy variable in your dataset that matches those conditions before plotting. So following your example, `"Condition" > 2.0 & < -0.5 == "YES"`. Then plot the red points for those values where your `"Condition" == "YES"` and invisible points for `"NO"`

This would also help with your follow-up comment regarding labelling the points.